# JUnit Test that ArrayList elements aren't duplicates

Tags: java, junit

Using this method that generates an ArrayList using random values from a called method getRandomInt. What would I assert to create a test method that tests that the ArrayList doesn't contain duplicates?

```
public static int getRandom(int min, int max) {

    return random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> getRandomIntegers(int size, int min, int max) {

    ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (number.size() < size) {
        int random = getRandom(min, max);

        if(!number.contains(random)) {
            number.add(random);
        }
    }

    return number;
}
```

Comment: Why use an `ArrayList`. `Set` (`HashSet`) will guarantee uniqueness for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact you have to assert more than that.
To check the actual behavior of the method, you should indeed assert from the returned list that :

- the list has the expected size

`Assert.assertEquals(size, list.size());`

- the list doesn't contain dup

`Assert.assertEquals(new HashSet<Long>(list).size(), actualList.size());`

- the list elements are in the range min-max passed to.

`for (long v : list){ 
    Assert.assertTrue(v " + " is not in the expected range", v >= min && v <= max);
}`

As  M. le Rutte underlined, I would also argue that the method API would make more sense to return a `Set` instead of `List` as an order of elements is not expected : the number are random.

And as a side note, your implementation is not efficient.
With a large range and a size requested close to the range size, you could loop much more than required.

Answer (score 7):

Using assertJ this is straight forward [common-assertions-for-java-collections-in-assertj](https://dev.to/iuriimednikov/common-assertions-for-java-collections-in-assertj-4h3g#collection-contains-no-duplicates)

```
@Test
public void noDuplicatesTest(){
    List<Integer> numbers = Lists.newArrayList(1, 52, 12, 39, 45, 98, 100, 565, 6, 13);
    assertThat(numbers).doesNotHaveDuplicates();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your elements into an Set and then compare sizes.

```
assert new HashSet(list).size() == list.size()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be to fill your `ArrayList` with `Integers` from min to max, and then call 
`Collections.shuffle(aList)`.

Comment: Would be rather inefficient. Exaggerated: `getRandomIntegers(3, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)`

Comment: Well, this answer isn't perfect, but for less extreme examples could be useful. I suppose in these extreme cases the THRESHOLD could be defined...

Comment: @M.leRutte, what about `getRandomIntegers(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to check if there are no duplicates,

```
assertEquals(number.size(),number.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()).size());
```

where `number` is your arrayList.
Use this

`import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals`

Comment: This is wrong. number can contain duplicates and still its size can be same. Nit: signature is assertEquals(expected, actual)

Comment: @Ajak6 what you're saying is wrong. If number contained duplicates then it's size will definitely increase. This solution is valid